# Time Complexities Given x amount of items

Tags: algorithm, math, time

I'm currently learning about time complexities of algorithms at uni and I'm having a hard time understanding.

If we have two complexities: 
x is n
y is n^2

To calculate 100 items it would take x 10 seconds
To calculate 100 items it would take y 5 seconds

How long will it take for 2500 items.

Would you take the complexity (n for example) then make it equal to 100 and it takes 10 seconds.

So it would become

100 = 10

Then work out time taken per item

100/10 = (time per item)

Then multiply it by the amount of items 2500?

Would this be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I'm afraid this is off topic for StackOverflow (as it's a question of forming and solving algebra, not programming).  But try phrasing the problem as two equations and then solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For x :

Linear time O(n), means that if the input is 25 times larger (from 100 to 2500), the running time would be 25 times longer, meaning 10 * 25 = 250 seconds.

For y :

Quadratic time O(n^2) means that if the input is 25 times larger (from 100 to 2500), the running time would be 25^2 times longer, meaning 5 * 25^2 = 625 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexities are a red herring here; they're irrelevant to the problem, which involves combining rates:

IN ONE SECOND:
    x does 10 items, and
    y does 20 items.

So together, x and y do 30 items per second.

So the number of seconds to do 2500 items is 2500 / 30 = 83 1/3 seconds.

Comment: Sorry I probably should have specified that they are separate not together.